# Problem with error handling in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

Im trying to create error messages in my discord python bot with this code:

```
@purge.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Please specify the amount of messages you want to clear. Usage: //clear <number>')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('You do not have manage_messages permssion')
```

but im getting this error in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/projects/bad bot/bot.py", line 132, in <module>
    @purge.error
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'error'
```

and I don't  understand why is it happening.

If needed the purge command:

```
@client.command
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send('Done!')
```

Comment: Please could you add the code for your `purge` command? So far from the error, I can only assume you didn't add the `@client.command()` decorator to it.

Answer (score 6):

You're missing the parentheses in your `@client.command` decorator.

Try changing it to `@client.command()` and you should be good to go.

---

**Reference:**

- [`commands.command()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.command)

Answer (score 2):

You gotta do it like this

```
@client.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    pass

@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount : int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send('Done!')

@purge.error
async def clear_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send('Please specify the amount of messages you want to clear. Usage: //clear <number>')
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send('**You do not have manage_messages permssion!**')
```